# Can i streaming audio to server use HTML5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, core-audio

Now, I'm building a conference application based on HTML and javascript.I want to know that, it is possible to streaming audio and video to the server using javascript?and I have to use any type of server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible through WebRTC. Here's a link: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/12/WebRTC-hits-Firefox-Android-and-iOS